# swift: can't reduce [sic] character array to string

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I realize this is a unnecessary question, but...  why can I NOT use reduce to convert a character array into a string?

e.g.,

```
let str = "this is a string"
let clist = Array(str)
let slist = clist.reduce("", +)
```

gives me: 'Character' is not a subtype of 'Uint8'
when

```
list dlist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let sum = dlist.reduce(0, +)
```

works

I know I can simply do slist = String(clist), but I just wanna know, ya know?

Swift 1.1 in playground of xcode 6.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `combine:` closure of

```
let slist = clist.reduce("", +)
```

- `$0` is the so-far accumulated result – a `String`,
- `$1` is the current element from `clist` – a `Character`.

There is no `+` operator which takes `(String, Character)` as arguments.

This would work:

```
let slist = clist.reduce("") { $0 + String($1) }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 1.2:

```
let str = "this is a string"
let clist = Array(str)
let slist = clist.map { String($0) }.reduce("", combine: { $0 + $1 })
println(slist) // "this is a string"
```